# Project is not recognizing constructor contained in a different assembly

Tags: c#, constructor, namespaces

I have one assembly that looks like this:

```
namespace AssemblyOne
{
   class MyFirstClass
   {
      public MyFirstClass(String param)
      {
         // Assign stuff
      }
   }
}
```

Inside another assembly, I am trying to create an instance of this class. So, naturally, I have tried this:

```
namespace AssemblyTwo
{
   public partial class SomeForm : Form
   {
      private MyFirstClass mfcObject = new MyFirstClass("Some String"); // Error here.
   }
}
```

I have added the other project as a reference and inserted the necessary using statement. However, the line above where I create this object is giving a compiler error:

```
'AssemblyOne.MyFirstClass' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments.
```

This works fine when the two are in the same assembly. Why is it not recognizing the constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `MyFirstClass` should be declared as `public`. Modify your code to become:

```
public class MyFirstClass
```

Otherwise, it defaults to be `internal`

Comment: This worked, thank you! I thought the default was public, so I didn't even try this. However (this is just for comment) it led me to another interesting error: AssemblyTwo was targeting 4.5 framework was targeting 4.0. I had to change the target framework for one of them in order to actually use them as a reference. That likely added to my confusion as well.